# PHP create tabled array for all youtube videos on a specific channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently designing a PHP-based website for a gaming clan, and was asked to see if I could have all the youtube videos they have on their channel listed on the website to allow members to directly go to them vs searching for them on youtube itself (keeping everything centralized to the clan website).

All the posts I've seen here reference the old, outdated and no longer available gdata api for doing this, and I am not 100% sure on how I need to do this with the new google api setup, if anyone can assist me with either a guide on how to use this new api, get a api-key for the channel, etc, or point me to where I need to actually go.

Never done this before for php so I don't even know where to begin outside of the original code example I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850237/get-video-links-from-youtube-channel-extract-video-ids-from-urls-and-store-them).

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this matter.

Comment: You can get list of all videos usung [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request) method

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`Youtube API v3`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). It is also listed all [`client libraries`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) available for many programming languages and can great simplify your YouTube API [`implementation`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/channels#channels-list).

Here is an example URL request that retrieves videos from a channel:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

You may use this thread as your reference in storing video in an array: [Getting the list of videoId in array using YouTube api v3 playlistItems and build another videos query to get statistics viewCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315987/getting-the-list-of-videoid-in-array-using-youtube-api-v3-playlistitems-and-buil)